# Is there a way to apply query filters in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am making an app that filters results according to the client's filters

my HTML:

```
<form method="GET" action="{{route('products.all')}}">
    <div class="filters">
        <select class="form-control search" name="gender">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Gender...</option>
            <option value="M">Man</option>
            <option value="W">Woman</option>
        </select>

        <label>Kids?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="kids" value="1">

        <select class="form-control search" name="order">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Order by...</option>
            <option value="discount">% Discount</option>
            <option value="news">New Arrivals</option>
            <option value="a-z">From A to Z</option>
            <option value="z-a">From Z to A</option>
            <option value="less-price">From cheapest to most expensive</option>
            <option value="more-price">From  most expensive to cheapest</option>
        </select>


        <div class="filters-all">
            Price...
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" class="start d-none" name="price-start" />
                <input type="text" class="end d-none" name="price-end" />
                <input type="text" id="sampleSlider" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <select class="form-control search" name="size">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Sizes...</option>
            @foreach($sizes as $size)
            <option value="{{$size->size}}">{{$size->size}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"value="Filter"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am collecting each of these parameters and checking one by one if they are not empty ...

Example of my code:

```
 $gender = $request->get('gender');
        $child = $request->get('kids');
        $size = $request->get('size');
        $order = $request->get('order');
        $price_start = $request->input('price-start');
        $price_end = $request->input('price-end');
```

//Example if all filters are not empty

```
        if (!empty($gender) && !empty($size) && !empty($order) && !empty($price_start) && !empty($price_end)) {
            switch ($order) {
                case 'discount':
                    $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                        $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                    })
                                    ->whereHas('childs', function ($query) use ($child) {
                                        $query->where('child', '=', $child);
                                    })
                                    ->where('gender', '=', $gender)
                                    ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                    ->where('discount', '>', 0)
                                    ->inRandomOrder()->paginate(12);
                    break;

                case 'news':
                    $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                        $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                    })
                                    ->whereHas('childs', function ($query) use ($child) {
                                        $query->where('child', '=', $child);
                                    })
                                    ->where('gender', '=', $gender)
                                    ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                                    ->paginate(12);
                    break;
                
                case 'a-z':
                    $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                        $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                    })
                                    ->whereHas('childs', function ($query) use ($child) {
                                        $query->where('child', '=', $child);
                                    })
                                    ->where('gender', '=', $gender)
                                    ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                    ->orderBy('brand', 'asc')
                                    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                                    ->paginate(12);
                    break;
                
                case 'z-a':
                    $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                        $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                    })
                                    ->whereHas('childs', function ($query) use ($child) {
                                        $query->where('child', '=', $child);
                                    })
                                    ->where('gender', '=', $gender)
                                    ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                    ->orderBy('brand', 'desc')
                                    ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
                                    ->paginate(12);
                    break;
                
                case 'less-price':
                    $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                        $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                    })
                                    ->whereHas('childs', function ($query) use ($child) {
                                        $query->where('child', '=', $child);
                                    })
                                    ->where('gender', '=', $gender)
                                    ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                    ->orderBy('price', 'asc')
                                    ->paginate(12);
                    break;
                
                case 'more-price':
                    $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                        $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                    })
                                    ->whereHas('childs', function ($query) use ($child) {
                                        $query->where('child', '=', $child);
                                    })
                                    ->where('gender', '=', $gender)
                                    ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                    ->orderBy('price', 'desc')
                                    ->paginate(12);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

//Example if all filters are not empty except gender

```
elseif(empty($gender) && !empty($size) && !empty($order) && !empty($price_start) && !empty($price_end)){
            
    
                switch ($order) {
                    case 'discount':
                        $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                            $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                        })
                                        ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                        ->where('discount', '>', 0)
                                        ->inRandomOrder()->paginate(12);
                        break;
    
                    case 'news':
                        $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                            $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                        })
                                        ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                                        ->paginate(12);
                        break;
                    
                    case 'a-z':
                        $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                            $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                        })
                                        ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                        ->orderBy('brand', 'asc')
                                        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                                        ->paginate(12);
                        break;
                    
                    case 'z-a':
                        $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                            $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                        })
                                        ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                        ->orderBy('brand', 'desc')
                                        ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
                                        ->paginate(12);
                        break;
                    
                    case 'less-price':
                        $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                            $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                        })
                                        ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                        ->orderBy('price', 'asc')
                                        ->paginate(12);
                        break;
                    
                    case 'more-price':
                        $products = Product::whereHas('stocks', function ($query) use($size) {
                                            $query->where('size', '=', $size);
                                        })
                                        ->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end])
                                        ->orderBy('price', 'desc')
                                        ->paginate(12);
                        break;
                }
    
... //More code checking if size, order and price are empty and the rest don't

else {
            $products = Product::inRandomOrder()->paginate(12);
        }
```

I would like to know if there is any more effective way to apply the filters so as not to make so many lines of code practically the same

I repeat, this works 100% but I have to check one by one if these filters are not empty ...

Comment: is this basically if a filter is present add it to the query, if there is an order add it to the query, or is there more going on there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my projects, I implement a filter like this. take a look I hope it makes some sense.

```
public function advance_cashback_filter(Request $request) {

    //create newQuery
    $cashbacks = new \App\Cashback();
    $cbs = $cashbacks->newQuery();
    //join CashbackAccounts,cashbackStores,cashbacksites with Cashbacks
    $cbs->join('cashback_sites', 'cashbacks.cb_site_id', '=', 'cashback_sites.c_site_id')
            ->join('cashback_accounts', 'cashbacks.cb_account_id', '=', 'cashback_accounts.c_account_id')
            ->join('cashback_stores', 'cashbacks.cb_store_id', '=', 'cashback_stores.c_store_id');
    //each where statement will use related request param
    if ($request->has('cbs_store') && !empty($request->cbs_store)) {

        $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_store_id', $request->cbs_store);
    }
    if ($request->has('cbs_account') && !empty($request->cbs_account)) {

        $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_account_id', $request->cbs_account);
    }
    if ($request->has('cbs_site') && !empty($request->cbs_site)) {

        $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_site_id', $request->cbs_site);
    }
    if ($request->has('to_date') && !empty($request->to_date) && empty($request->from_date)) {

        $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_date', $request->to_date);
    }
    if ($request->has('from_date') && !empty($request->from_date) && empty($request->to_date)) {

        $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_date', $request->from_date);
    }

    if ($request->has('from_date') && $request->has('to_date') && !empty($request->from_date) && !empty($request->to_date)) {

        $cbs->whereBetween('cashbacks.cb_date', [$request->from_date, $request->to_date]);
    }

    if ($request->has('cbs_canceled') && !empty($request->cbs_canceled)) {

        if ($request->cbs_canceled == 'empty') {
            $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_cancled', '=', '');
        } else {
            $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_cancled', $request->cbs_canceled);
        }
    }
    if ($request->has('cbs_receive') && !empty($request->cbs_receive)) {
        if ($request->cbs_receive == 'empty') {
            $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_recived', '=', '');
        } else {
            $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_recived', $request->cbs_receive);
        }
    }
    if ($request->has('cbs_returned') && !empty($request->cbs_returned)) {
        if ($request->cbs_returned == 'empty') {
            $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_returned', '=', '');
        } else {
            $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_returned', $request->cbs_returned);
        }
    }
    if ($request->has('cbs_refunded') && !empty($request->cbs_refunded)) {
        if ($request->cbs_refunded == 'empty') {
            $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_refunded', '=', '');
        } else {
            $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_refunded', $request->cbs_refunded);
        }
    }
    if ($request->has('cbs_paid') && !empty($request->cbs_paid)) {
        if ($request->cbs_paid == 'empty') {
            $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_paid', '=', '');
        } else {
            $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_paid', $request->cbs_paid);
        }
    }
    if ($request->has('complex_search') && !empty($request->complex_search)) {
        $cbs->where('cashbacks.cb_store_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->complex_search . '%')
                ->orWhere('cashbacks.cb_account_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->complex_search . '%')
                ->orWhere('cashbacks.cb_site_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->complex_search . '%')
                ->orWhere('cashbacks.cb_date', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->complex_search . '%')
                ->orWhere('cashbacks.cb_order_number', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->complex_search . '%');
    }
    if ($request->has('Export') && !empty($request->Export)) {

        return $cbs->select('cashbacks.*', 'cashback_sites.c_site_name', 'cashback_accounts.c_account_name', 'cashback_stores.c_store_name')
                      ->orderBy('cb_date', 'desc')->get();
    }
    return $cbs->select('cashbacks.*', 'cashback_sites.c_site_name', 'cashback_accounts.c_account_name', 'cashback_stores.c_store_name')
         
                    ->orderBy('cb_date', 'desc')->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the if statement on them without adding the **empty()**

```
    if ($gender && $size && $order && $price_start && $price_end) {
          //Your code actions when all values are not empty
    }elseif(!$gender && $size && $order && $price_start && $price_end){
          //Your code actions when gender is empty and other values are not empty
}
```

Comment: Ok but this is not a valid answer, the code is still very long. The question is, is there another way to apply the filters.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this thanks to the help of @abhay and this post:

https://m.dotdev.co/writing-advanced-eloquent-search-query-filters-de8b6c2598db

```
$gender = $request->get('gender');
        $child = $request->get('kids') ? $request->get('kids') : 0;
        $size = $request->get('size');
        $order = $request->get('order');
        $price_start = $request->input('price-start');
        $price_end = $request->input('price-end');

        $products = $products->newQuery();
        if ($request->has('gender') && !empty($gender)) {
            $products->where('gender', '=', $gender);

            $products->whereHas('childs', function($query) use ($child) {
                $query->where('child', '=', $child);
            });
        }

        if ($request->has('size') && !empty($size)) {
            $products->whereHas('stocks', function($query) use ($size) {
                $query->where('size', '=', $size);
            });
        }

        if ($request->has('order') && !empty($order)) {
            switch ($order) {
                case 'discount':
                    $products->whereHas('stocks', function($query) use ($size) {
                        $query->where('quantity', '>', 0);
                    });
                    $products->where('discount', '>', 0);
                    $products->orderBy('discount','desc');

                    break;

                case 'news':

                    $products->orderBy('id', 'desc');
                    break;

                case 'a-z':
                    $products->orderBy('brand', 'asc');
                    $products->orderBy('name', 'asc');

                    break;

                case 'z-a':
                    $products->orderBy('brand', 'desc');
                    $products->orderBy('name', 'desc');

                    break;

                case 'less-price':

                    $products->orderBy('price', 'asc');

                    break;

                case 'more-price':

                    $products->orderBy('price', 'desc');

                    break;
            }
        }

        if ($request->has('price-start') && $request->has('price-end') && !empty($price_start) && !empty($price_end)) {
            $products->whereBetween('price', [$price_start, $price_end]);
        }

return view('product.all_for_users', [
            'products' => $products->paginate(12),
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is as simple as when a filter is present to then add it to the query and if there is an order specified that is added to the query, you would just have conditionals. You can use the `when` method of the builder to add things conditionally instead of `if`s. A quick idea:

```
$query = Product::when(
    $request->input('size'),
    fn ($q, $s) => $q->whereHas('stocks', fn ($q) => $q->where('size', $s))
)->when(
    $request->input('kids'),
    fn ($q, $c) => $q->whereHas('childs', fn ($q) => $q->where('child', $c))
)->when(
    $request->input('gender'),
    fn ($q, $g) => $q->where('gender', $g)
)->when(
    $request->only('price_start', 'price_end'),
    function ($q, $r) {
        if (count($r) == 2) {
            $q->whereBetween('price', $r);
        } elseif (isset($r['price_start'])) {
            $q->where('price', '>=', $r['price_start']);
        } else {
            $q->where('price', '<=', $r['price_end']);
        }
    }
);

match ($request->input('order')) {
    'discount' => $query->where('discount', '>', 0)->inRandomOrder(),
    'news' => $query->orderBy('id', 'desc'),
    'a-z' => $query->orderBy('brand')->orderBy('name'),
    'z-a' => $query->orderByDesc('brand')->orderByDesc('name'),
    'less-price' => $query->orderBy('price'),
    'more-price' => $query->orderByDesc('price'),
    default => $query->inRandomOrder(),
};

$products = $query->paginate(12);
```

You should make sure to do validation on the inputs before handling them.